# Socket programmimg in C, need sample codes and tutorials

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I want to do socket programming in C. Where client and server are exchanging messages. I have the sample codes with me, but i wanted some elaborate links and tutorials for socket programming C, so that i can write effective and error free code. I will be working with WinSock library and not on Linux. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the standard response to this question is:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: a quick question, is the guide applicable to WinSock as well? is the WinSock api similar to sys/socket.h?

Comment: Yes, it is applicable to Winsock as well.  Winsock is based off of BSD sockets, which is what the guide covers.  In Beej's guide, read "1.5. Note for Windows Programmers".

Answer (score 3):

If found this book - [Effective TCP/IP Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615894)

(some older edition though) to be quite enlightening some time in the past.

And the all time book "UNIX Network Programming" by W. Richard Stevens is a great source to learn from and understand how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

See basic samples, [Complete Client Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737591(VS.85).aspx) and [Complete Server Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737593(VS.85).aspx).
All part of the original, and necessary, [Winsock Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741416(VS.85).aspx) .

Comment: thanks and i've been there already, needed some thing more to it, so i asked.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Windows® Server 2003 R2 Platform SDK Full Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=484269e2-3b89-47e3-8eb7-1f2be6d7123a&displaylang=en&Hash=u%2bzUH17Zc0vZu8EJqdC%2fshgwWjcKxjvCbGrY9s8HGBt1BbTJ3k2pH47JCcEBT%2fAdBdoU9hPf3S3W5aQlwec9ig%3d%3d) this have samples a lot.